# Map info window templates - iterate through table rows for multiple results?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

Some locations on my map are shared. A single location can have multiple listings. In my Fusion table, these appear as separate rows that share most column values.

When a marker is clicked, the map only displays one result in the info window. I want to customize my info window layout to iterate through each matching row and display the results, presumably with a foreach command.

For example:

```
{template .contents}
<div class="googft-info-window">

{foreach <local_var> in <data_ref>}

    {$data.value.col0}

{/foreach}

</div>
{/template}
```

Is it possible to iterate rows in a custom map info window? If so, what `<local_var>` value should I set that represents the rows?

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_GViz_infowindows.html) or [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_GViz_infowindows3.html) (use GVis to query the table and combine the rows)

Answer (score 0):

Query all needed rows data, for template before shown, and iterate them for structure.

Comment: That's what I'm after, but I'm struggling with the syntax. Example?

Comment: @user608684, i will help you tomorrow, will place here link on gist.

Comment: @user608684, check here documentation: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#RetrievingTable
 and parse response through for..in